# How to unlock frozen ball head?

Tags: tripod-heads, ball-head

My tripod ballhead ball is frozen (locked) is position, I cannot adjust the camera position, although the main knob in the head can rotate, the ball is frozen and very stiff.

Any idea how to unlock the ball?

My ball head is Oben BE-126T

https://www.obensupports.com/product/2051/Oben-BE_126T-Ball-Head

Comment: What have you tried ?  Have you asked the manufacturers for advice - they'll at least know what's a bad idea.  Is there corrosion from e.g. sea spray ?

Comment: "*main knob in the head can rotate*" Do you  mean the knob that has the blue stripe in the photo of the link you posted ?  If so have you have turned it **counter clockwise** as far as it will go ? Was it functioning properly and something changed?

Comment: Some ballheads can lock-up if the tightening knob is too loose when the tripod is transported. The fix for one of the famous ballheads was to lock it really hard repeatedly.

Comment: @StephenG: I have tried rotating the main knob counter clockwise as much as i can , and didn't help. There are no signs of corrosion and i didn't take it to the sea recently. I have rapproached the manufacturer and waiting for their advice,

Comment: @AlaskaMan: Yes, the main  knob is the one with the blue stripe.I tried to rotate it counterclockwise as much as i can but didn't help. It was functioning well before but sometimes it use to be slightly stiff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried something like WD40 or some other general lubricant? Things like that ball aren't necessarily specialized equipment, you should be fine to take some oil to it to loosen it up.

Comment: Didn't try it before, and i was afried from trying it . Will test it and let you know.

Comment: WD-40 is a water dispersant that will eventually evaporate and leave the ball dryer than before.

Comment: Today i have sprayed it with WD40, now the ball is moving but it takes a lot of efforts to do so, but still unusable for photography in the field.

Comment: I have used a lot of force to move the main tension knob counter clockwise, it was really hard, i thought i am braking the head, but finally it moved !! yes, now the head is smooth and i mounted the camera on it to try the wait and it is working perfectly! Thanks all for helping and advicing.